# Java: Method returns its own JavaDoc

Tags: java, javadoc

I would like to write a Java method that returns its own JavaDoc as a String. Is this possible?

e.g.:

```
class MyClass{

  /** This method explains itself in a great length and describes 
  the parameters for the   class. It is called whenever the parametrization 
  of that class (based on a config file) is incorrect to remind the user of 
  this class to fix it. */

  public String explain() {
      return "Here simply return the JavaDoc";
  }


 public boolean checkParams(){

    // check parameters
    // call explain if the check went wrong and return false
    // return true if everything went fine.       
 }
}
```

Comment: I think it is not because the compiled code (bytecode) doesn't store the comments. But this is just a guess, not sure.

Comment: what's the point to write such method?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that since it is removed from the compiled code. You might use annotations instead and write an annotation processor to read them.